# splitting string property and linking with other property

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects with 2 properties. One of those properties is a string, and the other is a string containing a comma seperated list. I want to have a split list of all parts with it's associated other property.

I have...

```
objectA
{
   string propertyX
   string propertyY e.g. "part1,part2,part3"
}

List<objectA> objectAs
```

And from objectAs I want a Collection containing...

```
{propertyX1, propertyY[0]1 eg. "part1"},
{propertyX1, propertyY[1]1},
{propertyX2, propertyY[0]2}
```

etc..

Comment: This isnt making a whole lot of sense at the moment, could you try being a bit clearer with what you have and what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use your class `ObjectA` to store both properties and `SelectMany` to flatten them:

```
List<ObjectA> flattenedList = objectAs
 .SelectMany(obj => obj.propertyY.Split(',')
    .Select(propY => new ObjectA { 
        propertyX = obj.propertyX ,
        propertyY = propY
})).ToList();
```

But i would store it without comma in the first place ;-)

Comment: its pretty hard to see the point why would I do such a thing :)

Comment: @MartinCh: sorry, i don't understand your comment. OP wanted a way to store his objects flattened, that means one object for every part in the comma separated list. Therefore i've (re)used his class since it's perfect for this purpose. Another less readable option was a `Tuple<string, string>` or so.

Comment: Its always worrying when the answer actually makes the question understandable. Tim, you have an uncanny ability to understand the most onscure questions.

Comment: I think when he says to store them without commas, he means to store your items in a collection, it's mutch better to keep collection data in a collection then use a .Join() only when you truly need the collection as a comma delimited string.

Comment: @TimSchmelter yeah I mean it in general why not to use List of Tuple, but thats just me, and you answered correctly so I am out :)